# My old rule does not work anymore with the latest version of arara

Tags: errors, arara

I have a rule which worked with the previous version of `arara`:

```
!config
# Open the every <filename>.<format> that can be opened
# The default for <filename> is the current file.
# The default for <format> is pdf. 
#
# Sample usage: 
# - if myfile.tex is the current file, all these open myfile.pdf
# % arara: showfile
# % arara: showfile: {format: pdf}
# % arara: showfile: {filename: myfile, format: pdf}
# and both these open myfile.log:
# % arara: showfile: {format: log}
# % arara: showfile: {filename: myfile, format: log}
#
identifier: showfile
name: Display
commands: 
- name: Show file
  command: >
    @{
      prefix = isWindows( [ 'cmd', '/c', 'start' ], [ 'xdg-open' ] );
      view = getBasename(reference) + '.' + format;
      return getCommand(prefix, view);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.format;
    }
  default: pdf
```

Now, if I try it with prova.tex:

```
% arara: pdflatex 
% arara: showfile 
% arara: showfile: {format: log}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

My rule does not work anymore

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
Impossible to find the file "prova.[pdf]"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Version 6.0 introduced a (breaking) change in how arguments values (either default or provided) are passed to the `command` logic. The rationale behind this change is because we have plans for a safer and easier rule format in the future, and having a proper, explicit type scheme would be very welcome.

You can refer to our [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2021-02-26) for a complete list of features and fixes in the version 6 series, as well as reading about them in our lovely [blog post](https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/arara/news/release-v6/). `:)`

Long story short, argument values are handled now as a list of string values, so `format`, as in

```tex
% arara: showfile: { format: pdf }
```

will be translated as

| Variable | Type (version 5) | Type (version 6) | Value (version 5) | Value (version 6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `format` | String | List of strings | `"pdf"` | `[ "pdf" ]` |

We need to update the way this value is handled in the `command` logic (note: I opted for the `.concat` method, but using `+` as in the original rule works exactly the same):

```java
view = getBasename(reference).concat('.').concat(format[0]);
```

*Explanation:* we get the first value in the `format` list (index count starts at zero) and concatenate it as suffix for the `view` variable, which holds a string value, so

| Variable | Value | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `format` | `[ "pdf" ]` | List of strings |
| `view` | `"mydoc.pdf"` | String |

Finally, we change this line from

```java
view = getBasename(reference) + '.' + format;
```

to

```java
view = getBasename(reference).concat('.').concat(format[0]);
```

which should do the trick.

The complete and updated `showfile.yaml` rule:

```yaml
!config
identifier: showfile
name: Display
commands: 
- name: Show file
  command: >
    @{
      prefix = isWindows( [ 'cmd', '/c', 'start' ], [ 'xdg-open' ] );
      view = getBasename(reference).concat('.').concat(format[0]);
      return getCommand(prefix, view);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: format
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.format;
    }
  default: pdf
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a tool to convert any rule to its version-6 counterpart?

Comment: @Diaa I am afraid there is no conversion tool because there's no way to guess it right. It was not a change of format but type. Most user-defined rules might be fine, as `getCommand` flattens lists anyway. However, if there's a complex logic inside the `command` section, things really get tricky and need to be manually sorted out. The reference manual points out to this change...

Comment: I am sorry for asking without complete example, but if I have this rule snippet `theWindowsCommand = getCommand(pathToBashExecutive, "-l", pathToSageStartfile, "-c", "os.chdir(r'" + pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder + "'); load('" + getBasename(currentFile()) + ".sagetex.sage')");
        return isWindows(theWindowsCommand, getCommand("sage", getBasename(reference) + ".sagetex.sage"));`, is there something that needs to change to be fully compatible with arara v6 and future versions? Here it is the full rule script https://pastebin.com/SbSngQNq.

Comment: @Diaa nothing suspicious there, it seems...